# Lighthouse requirement to add title to iFrame not working for amp-vimeo

Tags: amp-html, vimeo, lighthouse

Unable to set iFrame title for amp-vimeo and possibly other similar elements such as amp-youTube.

https://realestateu.tv/real-estate-license-ny-online/

At the top of this page there's a vimeo embed video. When running a Lighthouse report for this page the iFrame is marked down in accessibility for...

> "Names and labels - These are opportunities to improve the semantics of the controls in your application. This may enhance the experience for users of assistive technology, like a screen reader."

I have set a title in the amp-vimeo tag but this does not process to the iFrame tag that is generated.

Perhaps I'm missing something obviouse or perhaps this is not a supported feature.

Please advise.

Comment: You should file a bug issue at the AMP Github page.

Comment: And you should not use AMP. It must die.